# How to copy a picture from disk into the clipboard with win32?

Tags: winapi, clipboard

It's easy to copy text into clipboard with win32 API, but I want to copy a picture from disk (for example, D:\1.jpg) into the clipborad.

I search many webpages and I can't find something useful.
Please teach me how to do it.

And no MFC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Gdi+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798(v=vs.85).aspx) to load the image, get `HBITMAP`, and set the clipboard data. Gdi+ is Unicode only, so if using old ANSI functions you have to convert the filename to wide char. Example in C++:

```
bool copyimage(const wchar_t* filename)
{
    bool result = false;
    Gdiplus::Bitmap *gdibmp = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(filename);
    if (gdibmp)
    {
        HBITMAP hbitmap;
        gdibmp->GetHBITMAP(0, &hbitmap);
        if (OpenClipboard(NULL))
        {
            EmptyClipboard();
            DIBSECTION ds;
            if (GetObject(hbitmap, sizeof(DIBSECTION), &ds))
            {
                HDC hdc = GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
                //create compatible bitmap (get DDB from DIB)
                HBITMAP hbitmap_ddb = CreateDIBitmap(hdc, &ds.dsBmih, CBM_INIT,
                    ds.dsBm.bmBits, (BITMAPINFO*)&ds.dsBmih, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
                ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hdc);
                SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hbitmap_ddb);
                DeleteObject(hbitmap_ddb);
                result = true;
            }
            CloseClipboard();
        }

        //cleanup:
        DeleteObject(hbitmap);  
        delete gdibmp;              
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note that Microsoft recommends using `CF_DIB` to set bitmap clipboard data, but that doesn't work with GDI+. This example uses `CF_BITMAP` instead.

Gdi+ uses standard `GdiPlus.lib` library. It needs to be initialized as follows:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GdiPlus.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "GdiPlus")//Visual Studio specific

bool copyimage(const wchar_t* filename);

int main()
{
    //initialize Gdiplus once:
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    copyimage(L"d:\\1.jpg");

    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

Comment: @JonathanPotter I assumed if Gdi+ loads the image successfully then `GetHBITMAP`, `GetObject`, and `SetClipboardData` will be okay. Or is that a bad assumption? `GetObject` looks critical, I added error check for that.